Configure build and run environment for C++ DGB project
I have C++ "hello world" project in Visual Studio Code. I would like to build and launch this code from IDE, but I would like to do this in automatically and more easy way than I do it now.
My way:
According to my understanding I need to have tasks.json and launch.json configuration files.
I press run button that offers to create launch.json file:

I select c++ (GDB/LDDB) and I got almost empty launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}

Press Add configuration button and select C/C++ GDB (launch)
Got configuration in launch.json:
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [



        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}

But I still can't run/debug executable, because according to my understanding I need to generate task.json with task that should compile my program and I need to add preLaunchTask item in my configuration with current task name.
I go to command palette and run Tasks:Configure default build build task

Select create tasks.json file from template:

Select Others and got semi empty tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello"
        }
    ]
}

I can copy and paste task that builds cpp file from my other project, but can I somehow ask system to generate tasks.json that is able to build my code automatically and connect it to launch.json configuration in proper way?
